# Pass jQuery slider variables through to Laravel controller

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Currently, I am using the jQuery slider with range. What I want to do is, upon the user submitting the form, I want the two values (max and min) to also be sent over to the controller, so I can save them in the database. They are both currently saved in the variable `values`:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000000,
      step: 10000,
      values: [100000 , 300000 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - £" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      },
      stop: function(event, ui) {
            var values = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values" );
          }
        });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - £" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
```

I have `alerted` the variable and it echos the correct two variables. I am at a complete loss as to how to get the two variables, possibly split, over to my Laravel controller, once the user submits the form.

I usually get the form's variables through the `Input::get` method:

```
$id = Input::get('id');
```

But trying to access this variable always returns `NULL`

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/nTR6X9) of how to get it working properly. My guess is that you forgot to set the "name" attribute on the HTML input field.